# cd dinamico shell linux

Tags: linux, shell

necesito ejecutar una shell que haga un cd dinamico. Esto con el fin de que funcione en varios servidores no importa su configuracion de carpetas. La idea es hacer algo como esto:

```
var=$(pwd)

cd $var
```

en la carpeta donde esta el sh hay un archivo que necesito leer, pero siempre me arroja un "No such file or directoy", alguna sugerencia?. Gracias.

Comment: Dejame ver si entendí. ¿Lo que te da error es la línea de "cd .."?, ¿o el erro es más tarde al intentar usar un archivo de dicha carpeta?

Comment: Si usas ese código en bash, te va a "cambiar" al mismo directorio en el que ya te encuentras, ya que `var` obtendrá el valor del directorio actual, es decir, hará un cambio al directorio actual y no verás ningún efecto.
Puedes replantear tu pregunta para que quede más claro lo que estás buscando conseguir.

Answer (score 0):

Con bash funciona así:

```
var=$PWD 
cd $var
```